# Generating all binary trees of N nodes in lexigraphical order

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, nodes

I was just curious if anyone has an algorithm for how to generate binary trees of N nodes in lexigraphical order.

The very first binary tree would be a right chain of length N. The last tree would be a left chain of length N. I would like to know how to generate the trees in between the first binary tree and last binary tree in lexigraphical order.

A tree with 4 nodes would have 14 binary trees. 
A tree with 3 nodes would have 5 binary trees. 
etc.

EDIT:
So, when you predorder traverse a tree, if you hit a non-null node you output a 1, if you hit a null output a 0. So the tree is ordered from 1,2,3,...N. A tree of node 5 would have a right chain of 1,2,3,4,5 in this order. I was thinking theoreticially this could work: If I just take the lowest numbered leaf node and reverse preorder traverse one position and move this node to that position. If this node was originally a child of its node-1, and after reverse preorder traversing this node is no longer a child of node-1, than I shift all LEAF nodes less than this node to the best possible preorder position (which should probably be the most right branch).

Comment: what algo or logic did you try?

Comment: First, why should we do your homework?

Comment: You haven't defined what lexicographical order means in this case.  The concept usually applies to strings or sequences, not trees.

Comment: So, when you predorder traverse a tree, if you hit a non-null node you output a 1, if you hit a null output a 0. So the tree is ordered from 1,2,3,...N. A tree of node 5 would have a right chain of 1,2,3,4,5 in this order. I was thinking theoreticially this could work: If I just take the lowest numbered leaf node and reverse preorder traverse one position and move this node to that position. If this node was originally a child of its node-1, and after reverse preorder traversing is no longer a child of node-1, than I shift all children leaf nodes less than the node to max predorder positions

Comment: The numbers 14 and 5 are a clue. They are the Catalan numbers for 4 and 3, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you a direct solution. But I will give an solution here for a similar problem: Given n, generate all structurally unique BST's (binary search trees) that store values 1...n.

I think it is not hard for you to modify my solution a little bit to solve your problem.

```
public class Solution {
    public List<TreeNode> generateTrees(int n) {
        return helper(1, n);
    }

    private List<TreeNode> helper(int start, int end) {
        List<TreeNode> result = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();

        if (start > end) {
            result.add(null);
            return result;
        }

        // You just need to understand how below for loop works.
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            List<TreeNode> left = helper(start, i - 1);
            List<TreeNode> right = helper(i + 1, end);
            for (TreeNode l : left) {
                for (TreeNode r : right) {
                    TreeNode root = new TreeNode(i);
                    root.left = l;
                    root.right = r;
                    result.add(root);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}

public class TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;
    TreeNode(int x) { val = x; left = null; right = null; }
}
```

The solution is pretty straightforward using Dynamic Programming.